# SP2013 List: Hide Total of ms-gb. Show Total of ms-gb2

Tags: 2013, jquery, css

In a SP2013 List that is grouped by field 1 and then field 2, I need css or jquery help to hide the column totals at the first .ms-gb level but show the totals at the .ms-gb2 level.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hide the group totals in a SharePoint 2013 classic view

```
<style>
    .ms-gb>span{
        display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

### <s>Hide Totals for the first level only</s>

<s>$(".ms-listviewtable tbody[id^='aggrWP']").hide()</s>

### Hide Totals for the first level only  (ms-gb)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".ms-gb").parent().parent().next().hide()
});
```

Comment: Denis, 
This is not hiding anything on my list. 
I'm specifically trying to hide the totals for Group 1 but display the totals for Group 2

Comment: Strange. How are you adding css to the page/site?

Comment: Your code hides the count next to the group name. I have Totals or Sums of several columns. I need to hide the 1st level of Totals or the sum of several columns.

Comment: Sorry. My company doesn't allow me to see your image that you attached.

Comment: I see. I've updated the answer with a jQuery that hides the first level totals.

Comment: Denis, thank you very much for rewriting your code.  I Still have a question.

In my list view which is grouped at two levels, the totals looks like this:
- Grand Total
- Grouping 1 Total
- Grouping 2 Total
Your code hid the Grand Total which is great but I also need to hide the Grouping 1 Total. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to distinguish between Grouping 1 Total and Grouping 2 Total.

Comment: Sorry, I the last snippet was wrong. I have provided a new one (at the end of my answer). This time, I hope it will work.

Comment: Hmmm. I just tried it and no luck.  Denis, I really appreciate you working on this!  I wish I could decipher what to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122460/discussion-between-denis-molodtsov-and-chasepes).

Comment: Denis: Your code works now! Most importantly, you taught me how the code works and how to craft it for other uses!  Thank you very much for sticking with me on this!
Cheers-